# Fetching Single Record using two conditions in LINQ

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, linq-to-sql

I have a table which I am updating a single record using LINQ, but my condition to fetch that record is 2. My condition is this:

```
   Test p = dt.Tests.Single(c => c.ID == getID);
```

But I want to add another condition:

Where Cust_ID == 1. Something like this:

```
  Test p = dt.Tests.Single(c => c.ID == getID && t=> t.Cust_ID == 1);
```

But I cannot get hold of this situation using LINQ. Any help pls?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the lambda expression you should use the same alias

```
Test p = dt.Tests.Single(c => c.ID == getID && c.Cust_ID == 1);
```

Answer (score 5):

You need to put the logical operator inside the lambda:

```
dt.Tests.Single(c => (c.ID == getID && c.Cust_ID == 1) )
```

The inner parentheses are not needed; I added them to clarify that it's all one lambda.

Answer (score 3):

You're trying to use two separate lambda expressions for a single argument. I *suspect* you're looking for:

```
Test p = dt.Tests.Single(c => c.ID == getID && c.Cust_ID == 1);
```

If that's not the case, please give us more details about what you're trying to test in your conditions.

Answer (score 1):

```
 Test p = dt.Tests.Single(c => c.ID == getID && с.Cust_ID == 1);
```

Answer (score 1):

You're almost there, you just have the syntax wrong:

```
dt.Tests.Single(c => c.ID == getId && c.Cust_ID == 1);
```

You simply use the same symbol and combine the conditions.